# how to use static object in another project using api function

Tags: c#, reference, singleton

there are similar questions here but this one is specific. I have a solution and in it two projects. Main project and run time project, in order to use run time project i need to add reference to it in main project. In run time project i need to use static object from main project, in order to do that i need to add reference which i cant to because there would be circular dependence. I read that i could use API function how can I implement that? 
Thanks.

```
    namspace mainProject
{    
      public static MyClass Object;
}

public sealed class RuntimeComponentClass : IBackgroundTask
{
     BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;

     public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
     {
          _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

           //here i need to access static object from main project 

          _deferral.Complete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Static Methods can't be exposed using API calls.

Comment: What about static objects?

Comment: You can expose whatever data you want over an API interface.  Have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  (As an aside: Fixing the architectural problem which makes you think you *need* a circular reference sounds like a better long-term solution than trying to find a way to have a circular reference.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you cannot declare a static object just inside the namespace. I am assuming you have a class declared inside the namespace and static object is a member of that class

if you have following

```
  namspace mainProject
{    
   public class AStaticClass{
     public static MyClass Object;
   }

 }
```

you can definitely access the public static member from other classes.

```
  public sealed class RuntimeComponentClass : IBackgroundTask
 {
 BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;

 public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
 {
      _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        AStaticClass.Object is accessible
       //here i need to access static object from main project 

      _deferral.Complete();
 }
 }
```

However this is not a good idea to have static public member if you have any multi threading scenario.

Comment: RuntimeComponentClass is in another namspace in another project. I cant access AStaticClass.Object because i can't add reference to a project that conatins it.

Comment: Hi Petar, If you can't access class confaining static object you can't use it.  If you tell exact requirement and what you are after we might help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

This is in support of my comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I we solved the problem by moving all the classes in run time component project, in this way that one reference that exists is enough. Thanks everybody!